# htaccess rewrite ".../pages/about.php" to ".../about"

Tags: php, .htaccess, directory, url-rewriting

I've searched and found a lot of questions on this site and elsewhere that are very similar, but I've tried implementing and modifying all the suggestions I've found and none of it works. I realize this is a very basic question an I am extremely frustrated because nothing I'm trying is working.

With that having been said... I am trying to organize my content pages within kurtiskronk.com/pages/... (e.g. kurtiskronk.com/pages/about.php)

What I want to do is make it so that I can simply link to kurtiskronk.com/about ... So how do I go about stripping "pages/" and ".php"? I don't have a ton of content pages, so it's not a big deal if I have to specify for each page, though something dynamic would be handy.

NOTES: I am using Rackspace Cloud hosting, and WordPress is installed in /blog. My phpinfo() can be seen at http://kurtiskronk.com/pages/phpinfo.php

This is my existing .htaccess file (in the root)

```
php_value register_globals "on"
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

#301 redirect to domain without 'www.'
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.kurtiskronk\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://kurtiskronk.com/$1 [R=301,NC]
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{ENV:PHP_DOCUMENT_ROOT}/pages/$1  -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$     pages/$1  [L]

RewriteCond %{ENV:PHP_DOCUMENT_ROOT}/pages/$1.php  -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$     pages/$1.php  [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^blog/ blog/index.php [L]

# PHP - MAIL
php_value mail.force_extra_parameters -kurtis@kurtiskronk.com
```

I tested and the rewrite works with the line below (/about as URL brings up file /pages/about.php), but then the homepage gives a 500 Internal Server Error:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /pages/$1.php [L]
```

So I'm still sort of in the same boat as before, and as a follow-up, possibly more difficult question, if you go to http://kurtiskronk.com/weddings I am using SlideShowPro (flash) w/ SSP Director (self-hosted) as the back-end for it. When it pulls up a new image, it adds the following after /weddings ... "#id=album-152&num=content-9698"

There are four sections of the portfolio

```
# Homepage (kurtiskronk.com) id=album-148 ($id is constant for this section)
# Weddings (/weddings) id=album-152 ($id is constant for this section)
# Portraits (/portraits) id=album-151 ($id is constant for this section)
# Commercial (/commercial) id=album-150 ($id is constant for this section)
```

Assuming we get kurtiskronk.com/weddings to rewrite successfully without breaking anything, how would we make the total URL something cleaner kurtiskronk.com/weddings/9698 since the $num is the only thing that will change within a given section?

Comment: Perhaps you could start by scanning down lost of **Related** Qs to the right and find the ones that answers your Q.  Sorry, but this is a _very_ basic and commonly asked Q.

Comment: Terry I appreciate that this is a noob question to you, but I actually went through about 30 related posts (after looking for the last 2 days on google and reading up on htaccess files and rewrite rules) and not one of the solutions I've found works for me. If it is so trivial to you I would sincerely love to have your assistance getting this working.

Comment: Why do you use "RewriteBase /blog/" in the root .htaccess, instead of inside blog/.htaccess ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kurtis, thanks for the extra information.  It's a lot easier to give a specific answer to this.

My  first comment is that you need to separate out in your thinking URI space -- that is what URIs you want your users to type into their browser -- and filesystem space -- what physical files you want to map to.  Some of your mappings are URI->URI and some are URI->FS

For example you want to issue a permanent redirect of **www.kurtiskronk.com/*** to **kurtiskronk.com/***.  Assuming that you only server the base and **www** subdomains from this tree, then this cond/rule pair should come first, so that you can assume that all other rules only refer to  **kurtiskronk.com**.

Next, you need to review the [RewiteBase documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase).  `.htaccess` files are processed in what Apache calls a *Per-Directory* context and this directive tells the rewrite engine what to assume as the URI base which got to this directory and .htaccess file.  From what I gather, your blog is installed in docroot/blog (in the filesystem, and that you want to get to directory by typing in http://kurtiskronk.com/blog/ but that this .htaccess file is for the root folder -- that is the base should be (this goes before the www mapping rule)

```
DirectorySlash On
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteBase /

#301 redirect to domain without 'www.'
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.kurtiskronk\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://kurtiskronk.com/$1 [R=301,NC]
```

You can add some field dumps look for **REDIRECT_*** in the Server or Environment table in the phpinfo O/P to see if these are sensible. For example:

```
RewriteWrite ^(.*)$   - \
[E=TESTDR:%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/pages/$1.php,E=TESTPDR:%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/pages/$1.php]
```

Your next rule is that if the file exists in the subdirectory **pages** then use it:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/pages/$1  -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$                     pages/$1  [NS,L]
```

[Note that some shared service sites don't set up DOCUMENT_ROOT properly for the rewrite engine so you may need to run a variableinfo script (`<?php phpinfo(INFO_ENVIRONMENT | INFO_VARIABLES);` to see if it sets up alternatives.  On your site you have to use `%{ENV:PHP_DOCUMENT_ROOT}` instead.]

Your next rule is that if the file exists, but with the extension .php in the subdirectory **pages** then use it:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/pages/$1.php  -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$     pages/$1.php  [NS,L]
```

Now redirect any blog references to the blog subdirectory unless the URI maps to a real file (e.g. the blog stylesheets and your uploads.)

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^blog/ blog/index.php [L]
```

A complication here is that WP may be using a poorly documented Apache feature call Path Info that is a script can act as a pseudo directory so http://kurtiskronk.com/blog/tag/downtown/ is redirected to `docroot/blog/index.php/tag/downtown/` which is then executed by `` `docroot/blog/index.php `` using `/tag/downtown/` as the **PATH_INFO**.  But this is one for Wordpress experts to comment on.  If this last rule doesn't work then try:

```
RewriteRule ^blog/(.*) blog/index.php/$1 [L]
```

PS.  I like your site.  I wish I was that young again :(

### Postscript

When you say "it doesn't work", what doesn't with this `.htaccess`?

1. `http://kurtiskronk.com/phpinfo`,
2. `http://kurtiskronk.com/phpinfo.php`,
3. `http://kurtiskronk.comblog/tag/downtown/`

It's just that these rules work for these tests (with domain swapped) on mine. (One way is to move or copy the above `variableinfo.php` to the various subdirectories.  If necessary temporarily rename the index.php to index.php.keep, say, and copy the `variableinfo.php` to the index.php file.  You can now enter the various URI test patterns and see what is happening.  Look for the **REDIRECT_*** fields in the phpinfo output, and the **SCRIPT_NAME** will tell you which is being executed.  You can add more {E=...] flags to examine the various pattern results.  (Remember that these only get assigned if the rule is a match.

Lastly note the changes above especially the additional NS flags.  For some reason mod_rewrite was going directly into a subquery which was resulting in `redirect:` being dumped into the file pattern.  I've had a look at the Apache code and this is a internal botch to flag that further redirection needs to take place (which then replaces this or backs out).  However [this open bug](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=40781) indicates that this backout can be missed in sub-queries and maybe that's what is happening here.  Certainly adding the NS flas cured the problem on my test environment.

PS.  Note the added explicit `DirectoryIndex` directive and also that whilst `http://kurtiskronk.com` will run the root `index.php`, the explicit `/index.php` version will run the one in pages, because that's what your rules say.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer in detail, Terry. I'd forgotten why I had my htaccess set up the way it was, but it was for an old design where the blog was the front page...

Anyways, I've implemented your suggestions, but I still can't get it to work. Looking at my phpinfo() results it's not clear to me what to do with that. I've tried several other things such as %ENV:PHP_DOCUMENT_ROOT, etc. but I'm not sure what I'm looking for so it's all just guesses. http://kurtiskronk.com/phpinfo.php

Comment: Looking at your info file, it looks like you under mod_php5 are running on your on own dedicated VM which means that you should have access to the root apache config ('/etc/apache2/apache2.conf') and can enable Rewrite logging.  You've also got access to the PHPerror logs in `~/logs/php_errors.log`.  Let me look on a mod_php5 enabled config and get back to you :)

Comment: Terry, apparently I don't really have access to that stuff for the sake of Rackspace's overall security/integrity, but they did provide me with this link if it's of any help... http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/index.php/How_can_I_do_a_301_redirect

Comment: phpinfo is located in the root, not in /pages

Comment: None of those three things work with the htaccess using the rules specified (with or without the typos)

Comment: I've had some fun tracking this one down, but my advantage is that I've been going through the rewrite logs to see what is going on.  Basically a gash `redirect:` string was appearing in the URI -- AFAIK because of [this Apache bug](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=40781).  Disabling subrequests seems to fix it.  If you want to chat about this then we I can open a chat topic.  I'll update my post.

Comment: SUCCESS!!!! Terry, you are awesome. I haven't yet made sense of what exactly was done differently, but it now works without breaking anything I've noticed so far.

Comment: I am watching Kiss-Kiss Bang-Bang with the good lady at the moment.  We can go through some of the details and the other things that you want to work through in 3 hrs. See http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7292/conversation-terrye-and-kurtis-kronk

Comment: Hmmm, does it let me chat, actually? I clicked the link and it said I have to have 20 reputation to talk there. Enjoy the movie. :D

Comment: Kurtis, I am still learning the foibles of stackoverflow.  At least I tried!  R u on skype? my ID is terry.ellison.uk  Otherwise ping me an email at my user ID @ ellisons.org.uk and we can go through this crap.

Answer (score 0):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule /([0-9]+)$ /pages/$1.php [L]
```

Put something like this in your .htaccess file. I guess that is what you want.
Juest a redirect from a simple url to a longer url.

Comment: Both of these solutions just end up showing the standard WordPress 'not found, try searching' page. (WordPress is installed in /blog)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution. You can use it apache conf file(s) or in .htaccess (easier to set up when you're trying).

mod_rewrite has to be enabled.

For example, use .htaccess in your DocumentRoot with:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /pages/$1.php [L]
```

It will redirect /about to /pages/about.php, and any other page.
The "RewriteCond" part is to authorize access to an existing file (eg: if you had an "about" file at the root of your site, then it will be served, instead of redirecting to /pages/about.php).

Comment: Both of these solutions just end up showing the standard WordPress 'not found, try searching' page. (WordPress is installed in /blog)

Comment: OK, you did'nt tell us you had WP installed and already RewriteRules. It changes everything. The line "RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]" catches (nearly) everything. And a RewriteCond only apply to the next RewriteRule (except if there are more RewriteConds after). Try to move up the 2 lines I gave you (Cond / Rule) before this one.

Comment: Ooooo... combined with cleaning up my htaccess file, this does the trick! Editing my question with updated working htaccess code!

Comment: ^ After excitedly posting that, I realized that while it worked for rewriting, it also broke the homepage... doh!